# knex join jsonb array

Tags: knex.js, jsonb

I will try to simplify my problem in the best way that I can

I have this schema

```
table_01 (title, loc_id, ...)
table_02 (loc_id, rule_id, code, ...)
table_03 (rules_jsonb, ...)
```

the format for this JSON is the following

```
{"rules":
   [
     {
       "id" : 123456,
       "rule_name" : "R01"
     },
     {
       "id" : 852147,
       "rule_name" : "R02"
     },
     {
       "id" : 4236851,
       "rule_name" : "R03"
     }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the title and the name of the rule attached to it on knex

I was able to get this data on a single query like this:

```
select t01.title, value ->> 'rule_name'
from table_01 t01
join table_02 t02 on t01.loc_id = t02.loc_id
join table_03 t03 on t03.code = t02.code
left join jsonb_array_elements(rules_jsonb #> '{rules}') on value->>'id' = t03.rule_id;
```

so now, to my .js file

```
const data = await db
    .select(
      'title',
      db.raw('value ->> "rule_name" as rule_name '),
    )
    .from('table_01')
    .join('table_02', function(){
      this.on('table_01.loc_id', 'table_02.loc_id')
    })
    .join('table_03', function(){
      this.on('table_03.code', 'table_02.code')
    })
    .leftJoin('jsonb_array_elements(rules_jsonb #> "{rules}")', function(){
      this.on('table_02.rule_id', '(value ->> "id"))
    })
```

but I'm receiving the error that the relation "jsonb_array_elements" doesn't exist, how should I surpass this?

Answer (score 0):

after hours of trying and error plus a lot of doc reading, here's the answer if anyone else needs it in the future

```
.select(
'title',
db.raw("value ->> 'rule_name' as rule_name"),
)

.leftJoin(
      db.raw("jsonb_array_elements(rules_jsonb #> '{rules}')"),
      db.raw("(value ->> 'id')::uuid"),
      'table_02.rule_id'
    )
```